# How to set the dates range within two tables?

Tags: sql

I have two table which has dates: date_from and date_to.

I need to join them in a specific way.

When table 1 has range 2019/05/01 - 2019/09/30
and tabel2 has range 2019/07/01 - 2019/08/30

I need to cut them into 3 lines:

```
2019/05/01 - 2019/06/30
2019/07/01 - 2019/08/30
2019/09/01 - 2019/09/30
```

**Query**

```sql
select date_from, date_to, value
from table1
union all
select date_from, date to, value
from table2
```

The input is:

```
table1:  
date_from    date_to  
2019/05/01   2019/09/30  

table 2:  
date_from    date_to  
2019/07/01   2019/08/30
```

And the output should be:

```
date_from    date_to  
2019/05/01   2019/06/30  
2019/07/01   2019/08/30  
2019/09/01   2019/09/30
```

Comment: Three date ranges based on date_from or on date_to?  The 3 rows of dates above seem like output, please confirm.  But what were the sample input rows? Do they have just a single date?  Please also include.  What happens to value during the cut? Is it cloned onto three rows?

Comment: sample data please

Comment: Sorry for the code formatting. It's my first time on this page. I've added input and output.

Comment: What database is it ?

Comment: Still seems like a lot of trouble for just two pairs of dates.  Why not just write Select with two constants, Union Select with two constants, Union Select with two constants?  There is no other input data in table1 or table2 !!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server then here's one way to do it

```
with table1 as(
Select CAST('2019/05/01' as date) date_from , cast('2019/09/30' as date) as date_to
 )
,table2 as
(
 Select CAST('2019/07/01' as date) date_from ,CAST('2019/08/30' AS DATE) date_to
)
,som as (
Select date_from date1 ,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month, -30, date_from), 30) date_to from 
table1 union 
Select date_from ,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month, -30, date_from), 30)from table2 union 
Select DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, date_to), 0),DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month, 0, 
date_to), 30)from table1  

) Select * from som
```

o/p is

```
date1                       date_to
2019-05-01 00:00:00.000     2019-06-30 00:00:00.000
2019-07-01 00:00:00.000     2019-08-31 00:00:00.000
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000     2019-09-30 00:00:00.000
```